# Keras Time series prediction with pre trained model

Tags: python, keras, time-series

I have a pre tarined time series in Keras and want too get a prediction from a given date. Like that:

```
from keras import load_model
def predict(date, filename):
    model = load_model(filename)
    # Do domething to get input_data from date
    return model.predict(input_data)
```

So how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can save a `keras` model by

```
# assume model is the trained keras model
# save the underlying tensorflow graph
model_file = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as source:
    source.write(model_file)
# save model parameter 
model.save_weights("weights.h5")
```

Then the saved model can be loaded by

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

with open("model.json", "r") as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read())
model.load_weights("weights.h5")
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as model.save(model.h5) and model = keras.load_model(model.h5)?

Comment: I run a simple test, and it seems they are the same. BTW, I made an error in my original answer, already fixed that.

Comment: No, the step to write model to `json` file cannot be skipped, otherwise, there is no model for you to `load_weights` from.

Comment: model.save() is not the same as model.save_weights()

and model.load_weights() is not the same as model = load_model()